# Measuring performance time for TLS handshake

Tags: python, sockets, openssl, performance-testing, tls1.2

I have this sample code to measure TLS handshake performance time. The result I get is: `3.43 ms`. By repeating this for 1000 time, I get the minimum time below `1 ms`. I use a device with a public IP address. I also do not want to care about certificate/host validation. Just the handshake (client hello, server hello, etc. until the end of the handshake). I use domain name to connect to the server (e.g. google.com).

My question: the performance time result I get seems very small. Am I missing something or this is normal for a TLS handshake using my parameters?

The python code is:

```
import socket, ssl
import time
import datetime

context = ssl.SSLContext()
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TICKET #diable session ticket
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE # disable cert. validation
context.check_hostname = False  # disable host name checking
dn = "google.com" # example of domain to connect to
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # create socket
s.settimeout(5) # set timeout
sslSocket = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname = dn) # wrap socket into TLS context

try:
    begin = time.process_time() # start timer
    sslSocket.connect((dn, 443)) # TLS socket connection
    perf = time.process_time() - begin # end timer

    print ("Success! Performance time for TLS connection is: ", perf*1000) #convert from sec. to ms by multiplying with 1000


except (ssl.SSLError, ssl.SSLEOFError, ssl.CertificateError,ssl.SSLSyscallError, ssl.SSLWantWriteError, ssl.SSLWantReadError,ssl.SSLZeroReturnError) as e1:
    sslSocket.close() # close the socket
except Exception as e2:
    sslSocket.close() # close the socket
```

Comment: I think you should check if the SSL Connection Succeeded or not? How do you know if 3.43 ms is for a succeeded connection or a failed one?

Comment: @Jay I only care about the time for connections with domains who make a successful connection. I updated the code to include `try except` statement. If failed, just close the socket. I still get the small amount of time (google.com) makes a successful connection.